# Ionic 3 Slides Component - Implement next and previous button

Tags: angular, typescript, slider, ionic3, swiper.js

I am new in IONIC 3, I try to  implement Slider in my Ionic App and I try to Implement next and previous button for slide.

Like:

[image]

Please help me for its functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#navigating), you can call either the `slideTo()` or `slideNext()` methods. For example (taken from the official Ionic v2+ documentation):

```
this.slides.slideTo(2, 500);
```

This would take you to the third slide, with a transition time of 500ms.

For changing to the previous or next slide you could either use the `slideNext()` and `slidePrev()` functions or save an index for the current slide and simply increment or decrement it, while passing it as a parameter to the `slideTo()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can have **custom Next, Previous buttons** as shown in Image below

**Image & Complete Tutorial Source**:[**Link**](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-multiple-slides-on-single-view-using-swiper-slider/)

[image]

**home.page.html**

```
  <ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="1">
    <span class="slider-nav arrow-prev"
      (click)="slidePrev(sliderOne,slideWithNav)">
      <div class="prev-icon-custom custon-nav"
        [class.disabled]="sliderOne.isBeginningSlide"></div>
    </span>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="10">

    <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOptsOne" #slideWithNav
      (ionSlideDidChange)="SlideDidChange(sliderOne,slideWithNav)">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let s of sliderOne.slidesItems">
        <img src="../../assets/images/{{s.id}}.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>

  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="1">
    <span class="slider-nav arrow-next"
      (click)="slideNext(sliderOne,slideWithNav)">
      <div class="next-icon-custom custon-nav"
        [class.disabled]="sliderOne.isEndSlide"></div>
    </span>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
    @ViewChild('slideWithNav') slideWithNav: Slides;
    sliderOne: any;

    //Configuration for each Slider
    slideOptsOne = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay:true
    };

    constructor(
    ) {
    //Item object for Nature
    this.sliderOne =
        {
        isBeginningSlide: true,
        isEndSlide: false,
        slidesItems: [
        {
            id: 1,
            image: '../../assets/images/1.jpg'
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            image: '../../assets/images/2.jpg'
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            image: '../../assets/images/3.jpg'
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            image: '../../assets/images/4.jpg'
            },
            {
            id: 5,
            image: '../../assets/images/5.jpg'
            }
        ]
        };

    }

    //Move to Next slide
    slideNext(object, slideView) {
    slideView.slideNext(500).then(() => {
        this.checkIfNavDisabled(object, slideView);
    });
    }

    //Move to previous slide
    slidePrev(object, slideView) {
    slideView.slidePrev(500).then(() => {
        this.checkIfNavDisabled(object, slideView);
    });;
    }

    //Method called when slide is changed by drag or navigation
    SlideDidChange(object, slideView) {
    this.checkIfNavDisabled(object, slideView);
    }

    //Call methods to check if slide is first or last to enable disbale navigation  
    checkIfNavDisabled(object, slideView) {
    this.checkisBeginning(object, slideView);
    this.checkisEnd(object, slideView);
    }

    checkisBeginning(object, slideView) {
    slideView.isBeginning().then((istrue) => {
        object.isBeginningSlide = istrue;
    });
    }
    checkisEnd(object, slideView) {
    slideView.isEnd().then((istrue) => {
        object.isEndSlide = istrue;
    });
    }
```